# Kafka: GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group

Tags: apache-kafka

I have bare metal kafka cluster with sasl_plaintext authorization between clients and brokers.

```bash
export USERNAME="test-app"
export PASSWORD="password"
export TOPIC="test-app-logs"
export CONSUMER_GROUP="test-app-consumer-group"
```

I created topic `test-app-logs`, created user `test-app` in `jaas.conf`, setup ACL. Here are they:

```bash
$ bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2181 --list --topic $TOPIC
Current ACLs for resource `Topic:LITERAL:test-app-logs`: 
        User:test-app has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
        User:test-app has Allow permission for operations: Describe from hosts: *
        User:test-app has Allow permission for operations: All from hosts: *
        User:test-app has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: * 

$ bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2181 --list --group $CONSUMER_GROUP
Current ACLs for resource `Group:LITERAL:test-app-consumer-group`: 
        User:test-app has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
        User:test-app has Allow permission for operations: Describe from hosts: *
        User:test-app has Allow permission for operations: All from hosts: *
```

Now I want to produce some message and then consume it.

This works as expected.

```bash
echo "hello" | /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh \
--broker-list localhost:9092 \
--topic $TOPIC \
--producer-property security.protocol=sasl_plaintext \
--producer-property sasl.mechanism=PLAIN \
--producer-property sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='$USERNAME' password='$PASSWORD';"
```

This doesn't work:

```bash
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --from-beginning \
--bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
--group $CONSUMER_GROUP \
--topic $TOPIC \
--consumer-property security.protocol=sasl_plaintext \
--consumer-property sasl.mechanism=PLAIN \
--consumer-property sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='$USERNAME' password='$PASSWORD';"
```

The problem is that I can't consume topic with group.id `test-app-consumer-group`, because of the error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: test-app-consumer-group
```

I still can use partition instead of group, this works fine:

```bash
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --from-beginning \
--bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
--topic $TOPIC \
--consumer-property security.protocol=sasl_plaintext \
--consumer-property sasl.mechanism=PLAIN \
--consumer-property sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='$USERNAME' password='$PASSWORD';" \
--partition 0
```

What am I doing wrong? What are correct configuration of ACL should I have to be able to produce and consume message in new topic?

```
Kafka version: 2.4.1
Kafka commitId: c57222ae8cd7866b
```

Comment: Using partition flag doesn't use any consumer group since it's not using subscribe api function... Maybe you can try upgrading your cluster? Otherwise, I've had better luck with config files, rather than passing each property to the CLI

Comment: @OneCricketeer, hello, thanks for comment. I tried to update cluster on 3.5.1 version, but this have not helped. Same error :(

Comment: Perhaps you need additional ACLs on the `__consumer_offsets` topic since that is read first when using any consumer group? I've not personally configured sasl_plaintext ... When I have tried to setup security other ways, I have found this page to be useful (you can skip over anything Confluent specific) - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/security_tutorial.html#overview

Comment: @OneCricketeer, dude, you are awesome!!! IT works! thank you so much :) added access grant to __consumer_offset

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error described, that manually partition assignment works, and adding a consumer group does not, then that would isolate the issue to authorization around the `__consumer_offsets` topic.

Similarly, for producers, you'll want to add controls to the `__transaction_state` topic.

There are other internal topics used by other processes, but these are the defaults.