# Why is my KafkaConsumer stuck in a Joining Group Loop?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I have a KafkaConsumer that is stuck in a "joining group" loop.

It's a simple Kafka Python consumer, here is the python script:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import logging
import sys

root = logging.getLogger('kafka')
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
 root.addHandler(handler)

bootstrap_servers_sasl = ['node1.dev.company.local:9092', 'node2.dev.company.local:9092', 'node3.dev.company.local:9092']
topicName = 'test_sasl'

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    topicName,
    bootstrap_servers = bootstrap_servers_sasl,
    security_protocol = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
    sasl_mechanism = 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
    sasl_plain_username = 'test_user',
    sasl_plain_password = 't3st_us3r',
    group_id = 'test_group'
)

try:
    for message in consumer:
        if message:
            print(f"Received message: {message.value.decode('utf-8')}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An exception occurred: {e}")
finally:
    consumer.close()
```

When I include group_id when creating the KafkaConsumer, I will see this in the log over and over again forever, and the consumer will never actually see an item published to the topic it is supposed to be monitoring.

```
2023-09-13 08:35:44,102 - kafka.cluster - INFO - Group coordinator for test_group is BrokerMetadata(nodeId='coordinator-0', host='node1.dev.company.local', port=9092, rack=None)
2023-09-13 08:35:44,102 - kafka.coordinator - INFO - Discovered coordinator coordinator-0 for group test_group
2023-09-13 08:35:44,102 - kafka.coordinator - INFO - (Re-)joining group test_group
2023-09-13 08:35:44,104 - kafka.coordinator - WARNING - Marking the coordinator dead (node coordinator-0) for group test_group: [Error 16] NotCoordinatorForGroupError.
```

If I don't include group_id everything works fine.

The Kafka brokers are Confluent Kafka, with protocol version 3.4-IV0.

I can provide any other information, but am not sure what would be the most useful information to include.

The controller.log on the Kafka server side contains this:

```
[2023-09-13 08:56:03,345] INFO [Controller id=0] Processing automatic preferred replica leader election (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2023-09-13 08:56:03,345] TRACE [Controller id=0] Checking need to trigger auto leader balancing (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2023-09-13 08:56:03,345] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 0 HashMap() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2023-09-13 08:56:03,345] TRACE [Controller id=0] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 0 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2023-09-13 08:56:03,345] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 1 HashMap() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2023-09-13 08:56:03,345] TRACE [Controller id=0] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 1 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2023-09-13 08:56:03,345] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 2 HashMap() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2023-09-13 08:56:03,345] TRACE [Controller id=0] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 2 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
```

I'm not sure whether that is indicative of a problem, or just general information.

**Edit:**

Here is the server.properties file (from node1, there are three nodes in total):

```
broker.id=0

listeners=LISTENER_ONE://:9092,LISTENER_TWO://:9096

inter.broker.listener.name=LISTENER_ONE
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN,SCRAM-SHA-512
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
super.users=User:admin
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

advertised.listeners=LISTENER_ONE://node1.dev.company.local:9092,LISTENER_TWO://node1.dev.company.local:9096

listener.security.protocol.map=LISTENER_ONE:SASL_PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_TWO:PLAINTEXT

num.network.threads=3

num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka

num.partitions=1

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2

log.retention.hours=24

log.segment.bytes=1073741824

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

zookeeper.connect=node1.dev.company.local:2181,node2.dev.company.local:2181,node3.dev.company.local:2181

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=3

auto.create.topics.enable=false
inter.broker.protocol.version=3.4-IV0
```

I also ran kafka-console-consumer from one of the broker machines to test:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server node1.dev.company.local:9092,node2.dev.company.local:9092,node3.dev.company.local:9092 --group test_group --topic test_sasl --consumer.config consumer.config
```

With the following in consumer.config:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
        username="test_user" \
        password="t3st_us3r";
```

I don't get any errors, but also no indication that it is processing any of the test messages I produce (although when I run it without --group, I also don't get any indication that it is processing messages...this is different than what I am seeing with the Kafka Python client).

**Edit:**

I ran the following command:

```
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server node1.dev.company.local:9092,node2.dev.company.local:9092,node3.dev.company.local:9092 --describe --topic test_sasl --command-config admin-plaintext.config
```

Where admin-plaintext.config contains this:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
        username="admin-username" \
        password="admin-password";
```

The response is:

```
Topic: test_sasl        TopicId: Y3hiju-ZQsOvdRgLk4vpZw PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: cleanup.policy=delete,segment.bytes=1073741824,retention.ms=86400000,unclean.leader.election.enable=true
        Topic: test_sasl        Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,0   Isr: 0,2
```

Comment: I suggest you show your Kafka server config. Seems like replication and group coordinators cannot detect each other. You could also test `kafka-console-consumer --group test_group --topic test_sasl` from the broker itself

Comment: I added the server config.

Comment: `inter.broker.listener.name` needs to be the same between all instances. Do your other servers also have `LISTENER_ONE`? And why not use the default names like `SASL_PLAINTEXT` and `PLAINTEXT`? Can you also show output from `kafka-topics --describe --topic test_sasl`

Comment: After digging into this more, I think there may be an issue with my zookeeper configuration.

I will update after making and testing some changes there.

Comment: Worth pointing out that latest Kafka version does not require Zookeeper

Comment: The zookeeper thing was a red herring.

I have added the output from `kafka-topics --describe --topic test_sasl` above.

Comment: You need Zookeeper in order to use SCRAM, right?

Comment: Only if you have Kafka < 3.5.0 (or Confluent < 7.5.0) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14084

Comment: I see the ISR list has two replicas, so that seems okay. Also, `HashMap()` and `imbalance ... is 0.0` means your cluster is actually healthy. But I would still recommend you re-configure your cluster [using Ansible](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible), which should setup the server.properties more correctly. However, I would like to know the difference between `admin-username` and `test_user` that is in your python code

Comment: Or, maybe you need ACLs enabled on the offsets topic (as well as test_sasl) like this post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77083165/2308683

Comment: admin is superuser and its credentials are hard-coded in JAAS for the PLAIN mechanism (not using SCRAM) ... I would think that setting allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true would avoid the issue with no ACLs being set on the offsets topic, but maybe not?

Comment: I am wondering whether I perhaps need to set up the consumer groups ahead of time using the superuser, instead of expecting them to get set up automatically when the regular users try to subscribe (which is what we are currently doing in the existing systems that don't have ACLs)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible since there is no real way to "create" a consumer group without a consumer. When I worked with ACLs, though (we used Apache Ranger), we did need to add regex values into _that database system_ before groups & client-ids could subscribe. That was just a string comparison, though, not "creating a consumer group" in kafka

Comment: Sure, I meant creating an ACL for the consumer group, not creating the consumer group. I tried that, as well as creating an "ALL" ACL for __consumer_offsets, but the issue persists.